# jquery ajax webservice 304 and 200 Error ()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

web service is giving the problem 304 and 200 OK but it does not body of there code in chrome it is giving the problem of

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "webservice" Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

please guide me how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Enable cross-domain connections:

```
<script>
      jQuery.support.cors = true;      
      $(document).ready(function(){
      ....
      }
</script>
```